# Lazy loading not working when trying to access related entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is microsoft's scaffolding code for the action Details of the entity MyEntity:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    MyEntity myEntity = await db.MyEntities.FindAsync(id);
    if (myEntity == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(myEntity);
}
```

Now let's say I want to display the name of the owner of this entity in details.cshtml, if I write the following code:

```
<dt>
    Owner
</dt>
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.User.FullName)
</dd>
```

User shows up as `null`, even after trying to access `Model.User` to trigger the lazy loading.

**Edit:** Adding the model as requested

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your model? Assuming you have related entities, you can use .Include() to load related entities (Eager Loading). Or if you just access a navigation property, it will use lazy loading.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm already doing in my DisplayFor line? (accessing the navigation property)

Comment: I have added the model

Comment: I've testing "just accessing" the navigation property, it simply does not work

Comment: Put a stop before rendering the View and see if your model if being loaded correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add .Include("User") to your linq query.

Comment: This is my linq query: `db.MyEntities.FindAsync(id)`. If I add `Include(User)` then I can't `FindAsync()` anymore, I guess I could always resort to `Single()` but is this really the right way of doing this? It's strange that I have to change the `FindAsync()` pattern just to include related entities.

Comment: try using SingleOrDefaultAsync()

Comment: Also, will it load the users for every MyEntity or just for the found entity?

Comment: it will load the single "User" entity that is attached to the MyEntity model

Comment: and make sure you use Include("User") with quotes

Comment: I'll upvote this because it works, but this it not the answer I was looking for, I've changed the title of the question to make it more obvious

Comment: to use lazy loading just add "virtual" to your navigational property i.e  public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; } http://ovaismehboob.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/enabling-lazy-loading-in-entity-framework-code-first-model/

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, and Matt's answer led me down a similar road. I thought I'd share what I found.

[This article](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Task-based%20Asynchronous%20Pattern%20support%20in%20EF.#AsyncLazyLoading) indicates that Lazy Loading doesn't fit well with the Async pattern. Good to know.

With that, I looked into [eager loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eager). I found my answer there.

```
MyEntity myEntity = await db.MyEntities.Where(m => m.Id == id)
                                       .Include(m => m.User)
                                       .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Hope that helps someone else!